# Force UTF8 for Hubspot > Zapier > Webhook > CRM

Tags: utf-8, webhooks, zapier, hubspot, utf8json

I have a problem with my automation via Zapier.

In Hubspot I am creating deals and triggering those via Zapier.
Once my Zap is triggered the Data goes to my Webhook in JSON format.

The problem:
The data is non UTF-8

For some reason the Zapier formatter is working only for text and not for my solution.

Can anybody help here ?
tank you

Answer (score 0):

Your current flow is a bit unclear for me.

So are you creating a deal in HubSpot, and **that's** triggering a Zap with the info?

Or is the Zap creating the deal?

And it sounds like you have a webhook in Zapier that's receiving data. Did you select, "Raw", or just regular?

P.S. Screenshots will definitely help.